# The type System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder exists in both libraries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I recently did a fresh install of my PC. After installing all tools like VS2010 and VS 2012 i started getting the following error when building my MVC Solution:

```
The type 'System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder' exists in both 
'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll' 
and 
'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET WebPages\v2.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll'
```

I am usaing Windows 8, the Web Application targets .net 4.

How can i remove this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<runtime>` section of your web.config add:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think it should be version 2.0.0.0 of System.Web.Webpages. I adjusted the answer.